# Applying different color to points equal to zero in matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm trying, so far without success, to establish a fixed color to points equal to zero in matplotlib. As can be seen in the figure below, the points inside the circles are almost invisible since their color are similar to the ones applied to the points equal to zero. Is there some kind of flag that I'm missing or should I create a new array of colors instead of using the predefined colormaps?

```py
def plot_scatter_x_y(**options):
        label_format_sci = options.get('label_format_sci')
        xaxis = options.get('xaxis')
        yaxis = options.get('yaxis')
        zaxis = options.get('zaxis')
        xaxis_label = options.get('xaxis_label')
        yaxis_label = options.get('yaxis_label')
        zaxis_label = options.get('zaxis_label')
        title = options.get('title', 'Fig. title')
        bullet_size = options.get('bullet_size')

        fig = plt.figure(figsize=(2, 2))
        ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

        cmap_range = yaxis
        if zaxis:
            cmap_range = zaxis
            plt.axis('equal')

        p = plt.scatter(xaxis, yaxis, c=cmap_range, cmap=plt.cm.get_cmap(options.get('colormap'), options.get('colormap_range')), s=bullet_size, edgecolor='black', linewidths=0, marker = 's')

        if label_format_sci:
            plt.ticklabel_format(style='sci', axis='y', scilimits=(0,0))

        plt.title(title)
        plt.xlabel(xaxis_label)
        plt.ylabel(yaxis_label)
        plt.xlim(min(xaxis), max(xaxis))
        plt.ylim(min(yaxis), max(yaxis))
        plt.xticks(np.linspace(min(xaxis), max(xaxis), 5))
        plt.yticks(np.linspace(min(yaxis), max(yaxis), 5))

        #legend
        if zaxis:
            cbar = plt.colorbar(p, format='%.0e', orientation='horizontal')#, pad=0.1)
            cbar.set_label(zaxis_label)#, rotation=90, labelpad=0)
            cbar.set_ticks(np.linspace(min(zaxis), max(zaxis), 5))

        fig.savefig(f"{options.get('path_fig')}.pdf", bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)
        plt.close('all')

# test
xaxis =  [0, 1, 2, 3]
yaxis =  [0, 1, 2, 3]
zaxis =  [0, 1, 5, 0]
xaxis_label = "X-axis"
xaxis_label = "Y-axis"
title = "Title"

plot_scatter_x_y(xaxis=xaxis, xaxis_label=xaxis_label, yaxis=yaxis, yaxis_label=yaxis_label, title=title, path_fig=f'figure', colormap='inferno', colormap_range=1, label_format_sci=True)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to do with a new array of colors. It seems like overkill for such a simple thing.

```py
def plot_scatter_x_y(**options):
        label_format_sci = options.get('label_format_sci')
        xaxis = options.get('xaxis')
        yaxis = options.get('yaxis')
        zaxis = options.get('zaxis')
        xaxis_label = options.get('xaxis_label')
        yaxis_label = options.get('yaxis_label')
        zaxis_label = options.get('zaxis_label')
        title = options.get('title', 'Fig. title')
        bullet_size = options.get('bullet_size')

        colormap = options.get('colormap')
        colormap_range = options.get('colormap_range')

        original_cmap = cm.get_cmap(colormap, colormap_range)
        newcolors = original_cmap(np.linspace(0, 1, 256))
        zero_color = np.array([230/256, 230/256, 230/256, 1])
        newcolors[0, :] = zero_color
        newcmp = ListedColormap(newcolors)

        fig = plt.figure(figsize=(2, 2))
        ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

        cmap_range = yaxis
        if zaxis:
            cmap_range = zaxis
            plt.axis('equal')

        p = plt.scatter(xaxis, yaxis, c=cmap_range, cmap=plt.cm.get_cmap(newcmp, colormap_range), s=bullet_size, edgecolor='black', linewidths=0, marker = 's')

        if label_format_sci:
            plt.ticklabel_format(style='sci', axis='y', scilimits=(0,0))

        plt.title(title)
        plt.xlabel(xaxis_label)
        plt.ylabel(yaxis_label)
        plt.xlim(min(xaxis), max(xaxis))
        plt.ylim(min(yaxis), max(yaxis))
        plt.xticks(np.linspace(min(xaxis), max(xaxis), 5))
        plt.yticks(np.linspace(min(yaxis), max(yaxis), 5))

        #legend
        if zaxis:
            cbar = plt.colorbar(p, format='%.0e', orientation='horizontal')#, pad=0.1)
            cbar.set_label(zaxis_label)#, rotation=90, labelpad=0)
            cbar.set_ticks(np.linspace(min(zaxis), max(zaxis), 5))

        fig.savefig(f"{options.get('path_fig')}.pdf", bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)
        plt.close('all')

# test
xaxis =  [0, 1, 2, 3]
yaxis =  [0, 1, 2, 3]
zaxis =  [0, 1, 5, 0]
xaxis_label = "X-axis"
xaxis_label = "Y-axis"
title = "Title"

plot_scatter_x_y(xaxis=xaxis, xaxis_label=xaxis_label, yaxis=yaxis, yaxis_label=yaxis_label, title=title, path_fig=f'figure', colormap='inferno', colormap_range=1, label_format_sci=True)
```

[image]